# Minecraft Forge: Using correct Join Game listener for setLocationAndAngles

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft-forge

Using Forge 1.8.9 in Eclipse (Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)) in local development environment.

The goal is to set a player's location to a predetermined xyz every time they join (or re-join) a world. So if they quit the game, but then come back to the world, they will start in the same location as determined by the code below instead of wherever they left off. Basically, it will work like a lobby, where players start in the same place each time.

The code works using the chat component (e.g. the chat message appears upon joining the game) but I've commented it out, for now. The player simply appears wherever they left off after having left the game from last time around.

Questions are:
1. is the PlayerLoggedInEvent the best event to use, or is there a better event?
2. is setLocationAndAngles the best to use, or should a different set location type event (or move) better?

Thanks in advance. Lots of experience with LAMP stack, but Java and mods are a new interest (obvs). Code is below.

```
   import net.minecraftforge.client.event.RenderPlayerEvent;
//import net.minecraft.util.ChatComponentText;
//import net.minecraft.util.EnumChatFormatting;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraftforge.event.entity.EntityJoinWorldEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.PlayerEvent.PlayerLoggedInEvent;
//import cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;

public class JoinGameLocation {
    @SubscribeEvent
    public void SpawningLocation(PlayerLoggedInEvent event){
        event.player.setLocationAndAngles(145, 72, 145, 0, 0);
        //-----This works when uncommented
        //event.player
        //.addChatMessage(
        //      new ChatComponentText(
        //              EnumChatFormatting.RED + "You joined the game"));
        //event.world.setWorldTime(0);
        int ticks = 0;
        double good_x = 145;
        double good_y = 72;
        double good_z = 145;
        event.player.setLocationAndAngles(good_x, good_y, good_z, 0, 0);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the entity join world and the clone event

```
      @SubscribeEvent
      public void onClonePlayer(PlayerEvent.Clone event) {

      }

      @SubscribeEvent
      public void onEntityJoinWorld(EntityJoinWorldEvent event) {
          if (event.entity != null && event.entity instanceof EntityPlayer && !event.entity.worldObj.isRemote) {
          }
      }
```

The clone event is triggered upon tp, dimension change, etc...
The join world obviously when the world is joined. I suggest you play around with these.

Comment: OK, I'll check it out. I had a different variation where the world rendering would fail, but the relocation would work. I'll let you know. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, persistence of location isn't the issue, resetting the location fresh is, so I don't think Clone is it. I had tried The EntityJoinWorldEvent and it causes the world to return a "Wrong Location!" error. I did some reading on that but it was fruitless. Console: `
[21:12:44] [Server thread/INFO]: Player534 joined the game
[21:12:45] [Server thread/WARN]: Wrong location! (9, 9) should be (8, 6), EntityPlayerMP['Player534'/828, l='world', x=145.00, y=72.00, z=145.00]
[21:12:55] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving and pausing game...
[21:12:55] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for lev...`

Comment: Cross-posting this with [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503721/minecraft-forge-entityjoinworldevent-returns-wrong-location-error] as one of my variations.